# Python memory release upon reset tkinter objects containing objects containing objects

Tags: python, memory, tkinter, garbage-collection

I have a GUI application in Python 3.x. The GUI object contains other class instances, which contains other class instances and there's also variables throughout. I have made a reset button which runs `GUI.destroy()` and then an outside function which says `del GUIobject` and then recreates it as a fresh object.

I have been watching my memory in task manager while using the reset button like 30 times, every time after using the program a bit (not spamming it) and the memory usage only goes up, never down.

Is this a problem with garbage collection? Do I need to call `del` on the objects inside the GUI object? What can I do to release the memory to where it was when I first opened the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing your program...I would suggest that you look at:

[Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)

Zombies could be a problem if you are running your processes on a server, especially if the server is running LINUX. (in my experience)

Would need to see your code,

Dr t